# OpenGL | Render Vertex at UV coordinate

Tags: opengl, fbo

I'm using OpenGL and I need to render the vertecies of a 3D model to a FBO at the UV coordinate of the vertex. To do that, I first have to convert the UV coordinate space to the screen space.

[image]

[image]

I came to the conclusion that:

```
uv.x * 2 - 1
uv.y * 2 - 1
```

…should do the trick.

I used that in my vertex shader to place the vertex at those new positions. The result looks like this:

[image]

…while it should should look like this:

[image]

It seems like it's scaled up. I dont know where the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why can't you include your images directly? You should be able to place them by using the image upload feature of the SO editor.

Comment: New accaunt does not allow me to add them directly

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that.

Comment: I've embedded the images on your behalf. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you gfullam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the problem, I did not call gl viewport which was the reason the coordinate system wasn't applied to the fbo texture size

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that your screen space spans -1 to 1 rather than -0.5 to 0.5?

Try just subtracting 0.5 from both x and y.

Comment: I'm going to try it

Comment: And yes, the OpenGL space spans from -1 to 1