# Rotate 2D Vector with an Aspect Ratio

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, aspect-ratio

Many of us are familiar with the approach to rotating a 2D vector around the origin given an angle `theta`:

```
newX = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
newY = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);
```

I'm now trying to rotate coordinates in image UV space, which looks like this:

[image: UV Space]

(Image borrowed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938722/opengl-render-vertex-at-uv-coordinate) SO question.)

Here the units of the `u` axis are wider than those of the `v` axis, so the approach above leads to the coordinates rotating around an ellipse as opposed to a circle. I need the rotation of the vector to act as though the coordinates were square, meaning the aspect ratio needs to be accounted for. I thought it'd be as simple as stretching the coordinates to a square space, rotating, then stretching back, although it still appears that the vectors are rotating elliptically:

```
newX = (x * cos(theta) * Aspect - y * sin(theta)) / Aspect;
newY = x * sin(theta) * Aspect + y * cos(theta);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your approach looks right. Perhaps you're using the wrong value for Aspect? Try using 1/the value you're using now.

Comment: So you want the “0.5 | 1” point at the top to cross the horizontal midline well short of the side of the rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

The general version for rotation and aspect ratio is:

(center_c, center_y) being the center of rotation

(aspect_x, aspect_y) being the aspect_ratio

```
tmp_x = (x-center_x)/aspect_x
tmp_y = (y-center_y)/aspect_y
tmp_x = tmp_x * cos(theta) - tmp_y * sin(theta)
tmp_x = tmp_x * sin(theta) + tmp_y * cos(theta)
new_x = aspect_x*tmp_x-center_x
new_y = aspect_y*tmp_x-center_y
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried moving the aspect ratio part to outside the sin/cos part like in your example, and it still appears to be moving elliptically

Comment: Is your rotation centre (0,0) ? Pick one of your points say (x1, y1)and rotate by pi/2 you should get a point with coordinate (-y1, x1) if that's not what you get please provide numeriacl values.

Comment: I found the issue, turns out I was clumsily using the wrong values to calculate my aspect ratio. Now both approaches (the original one in the question as well as the one you presented) work flawlessly. Thank you for the help!